# Quickly identify multiple tables in csv-files?

Tags: python, csv, unix, command-line

I am having a lot of csv files, from which I have to extract the path and the headers. The python script that I am using for this purpose works like a charm:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import csv
thisdir = os.getcwd() 

# Create empty list for csvfiles
csvfiles = []

# Extract file-paths and append them to "csvfiles"
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for file in f:
        if ".csv" in file:
            csvfiles.append(os.path.join(r, file))

# Create header-extraction function:
def get_csv_headers(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",") 
        return next(reader)

# Create empty list for headers
headers=[]

# Extract headers with the function and append them to "headers" list
for l in csvfiles:
    headers.append(get_csv_headers(l))

with open('text.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',') # In EU: use semicolon; else comma
    for path, header in zip(csvfiles, headers):
        writer.writerow(list(path.split("/")[1:]) + header)
```

**But! I just realized that some of the csv files is containing multiple tables!** 
There is no consistency in how the tables is "separated" - some have multiple rows of space, and some none. The headers all contain letters and the table rows numbers (some followed by letters). 
It seems like a tedious task to go through all the +200 csv files to check if there is multiple tables in single csv files.

Are you aware of any way where I quickly can identify which csv files contains multiple tables (command line or similar), extract headers of multiple tables in one csv - or other creative ideas where I don't have to open and go through all csv files. Any ideas (command line/python) are very (!) welcome!

Thank you!

Cheers, Birgitte

Comment: All headers are letters only, no numbers?

Comment: I believe CSV files are intended to be single table files.  Since it is non-standard, you would need to study the format of the files provided to identify how the process or person generating the files is doing so.
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: Thanks for your answers - all headers start with letters, some contain numbers like "WP2.2". Unfortunately, there is not a single person that has generated the files, they are a mix of proper csv and excel files converted into csv, the formats are therefore not uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know, which file contains how many headers (assuming there are no numbers in the header):

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
  for /f %%i in ('findstr /v "[0-9]" "%%f" ^|find /c /v ""') do (
    echo there are %%i Headers in %%f
  ) 
)
```

The outer `for` iterates over your `.csv` files, the inner `for` gets the count of headers per file by filtering lines without numbers (with `findstr /v "[0-9]`) and counting them (with `find /c`).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately some of the headers contain numbers like "WP2.2" - but it is still useful :)

Comment: hm - No header starting with a number and no value-line starting with a letter? Then `findstr /vb "[0-9]" ...` should do (`/b` is `line starting with...`)

Comment: Thank you :-) I just identified a few files, so it works!

Comment: tag: Python? ^^